# Displaying different menu to verified users

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-fortify

How can I get this working:

```
<ul>
    @guest
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#signup">Sign up</a></li>
    @endguest

    @verified
    <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#logout">Log out</a></li>
    @endverified
</ul>
```

Or is it save to stick with:

```
<ul>
    @guest
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#signup">Sign up</a></li>
    @endguest

    @auth
        @if (auth()->user()->email_verified_at)
            <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#logout">Log out</a></li>
        @endif
    @endauth
</ul>
```

It seems that this doesn't work:

```
<ul>
    @guest
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#signup">Sign up</a></li>
    @endguest

    @auth('verified')
    <li><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#logout">Log out</a></li>
    @endauth
</ul>
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use version 8.12

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? 
`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I tried.. But when using `@auth('verified')` I get: `Auth guard [verified] is not defined.`

Comment: Which authentic method your are using? Laravel has ui auth, breeze, fortify

Comment: I use Laravel Fortify

Comment: `@auth('verified')` tries to check if an user for the 'verified' guard exists. No such guard is present in a default installation. If you want a custom blade directive (`@verified`), you need to define it in a service provider before being able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following in one of your ServiceProvider classes's `boot` method.

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::if('verified', function ($guard = null) {
            return "<?php if(auth($guard)->check() && auth($guard)->user()->email_verified_at): ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it in your blade views as follows

```xml
@verified
  user is authenticated and verified
@endverified
```

[Extending Blade - Custom If Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#custom-if-statements)